# Xcode 6 OS X Submission Error: iOS Apps must have a provisioning profile

Tags: macos, xcode6, provisioning-profile

I'm having the worst time ever submitting an update to my Mac app. Everything was fine until I updated to Xcode 6. I'm in Mavericks, 10.9.4. I get the following error:
iTunes Store operation failed.
Unable to process application at this time due to the following error: iOS Apps must have a provisioning profile.

I have no idea why it says "iOS." Don't know if that's an Xcode bug or it thinks I'm making an iOS app. I used the same Xcode project file to submit the Mac app in the previous Xcode.

I have tried the following with no results:
• Revoked and deleted all certificates and provisioning profiles and started over. 
• I created all certificates, provisioning profiles manually rather than Xcode managing them. 
• Set the provisioning profile in "release" in the target and in a different occasion, in the project file.
• Gone into the project info and created a separate configuration.

The only "weird" thing I would say that I could be doing insanely obviously wrong is when I look at the options for code singing identity for release, it says "Mac Developer:yata" but there is no option for "Mac Distribution:(myname)" Should there be? I didn't need that in the past. Also, the only options that I can select are in a section called "identities in keychain." Should there be another section? "Identities in Xcode?"

Thank you for anyone that can help. I'll try pretty much anything at this point.

Comment: before you submit, you should always validate, did you?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes, that's where the error happens, during validation.

Comment: if it's a mac app, the certificate should be 3 party mac developer, and now they have 2 new dropdown when submitting, one is to select the provisonning profile the other one is to match the app name. make sure that is correct

Comment: Okay so I have the option for 3rd party mac dev and when I select it, I also can select the provisioning profile I created manually at the dev center. When I archive I get the same error.

Comment: I also tried using the provisioning profile Xcode created but got the same result.

Comment: Got the same error after update xCode. Try to regenerate everything and no luck. I think this is a xCode bug =(

Comment: Thanks @winsergy I really tried regenerating everything both manually and having Xcode automatically do it and still the same error. But the good news is I have a helper app so the user can "open at login" and when I don't include the helper, the app submits with no errors. So at least I know it's the helper. Problem is I have no idea how to fix it. It has it's own app id and provisional profile and whether I get rid of it or leave it be with it's own provisional profile, I get the same error.

Comment: @JimBak I have this feature too (lunch on login), but before I upgrade xCode to Version 6.0.1 (6A317) - everything was OK.

Comment: @JimBak **UPDATE** I was solve this case for myself - [http://stackoverflow.com/a/25972350/1067147](read my answer below). Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so our problem was that our company name had an apostrophe in it ---- could have the same issue if you have quotes in your company name as well. I contacted Apple for them to change it and then uploading worked from Xcode 5.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for my case:

[image: Mac app with iOS validating error]

I got error in validation stage.

On organizer we see:
[image: xCode->Organizer]

1) Go to [Apple download page](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#) and download xCode 5.1.1

2) Double click on xcode_5.1.1.dmg

3) Copy xCode.app to Desktop

4) Rename xCode.app -> xCode511.app

5) Move xCode511.app -> Applications
[image]

6) Close xCode 6.1

7) Work with validation and upload in xCode511.app
[image: Well done!]

**UPDATED**

8) Be careful ! [ITC.apps.validation.prerelease_build_missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25893878/issue-at-appstore-ios-app-new-version-submission)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have `Xcode` right now, but here are the steps:

1. Delete your certificate and provisioning, both your mac and iTunes account
2. Regenerate the `certificates` and `provisioning profile` (distribution)
3. Download double click
4. Go to the `account` tab, then `view account`
5. All certificates and profiles will be listed refresh the stuff there
6. Clean and rebuild your app with the right provision and `3 party Mac developer`
7. archive, validate and submit (select the right provison and match the app)

voila!

**EDIT**

Everything you will ever need to know :

**https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html**

Comment: Im not sure what else to suggest , have you tried with xcode 5.1 ?

Comment: Yes : ( Same exact error. I have tried everything I can find on the web multiple times.

Comment: Im sure this will help https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Meda do you know if your provisional distribution profiles are supposed to be listed if you go to Xcode -> Organizer -> devices -> right click on your Mac and say "Show provisional profiles"  ? I am trying to add my provisional profiles there. It's letting me select them and click "install" but then it doesn't appear on the list.

Comment: Correct. That's what I see too for mine. What about if you go to the "window" menu, organizer, then click the devices tab and look at your provisional profiles in your device? Do you see them listed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61385/discussion-between-meda-and-jim-bak).

Comment: @jim unfortunately I dont have access to my mac right now, do you see it there ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem... finally I click on Submit and it worked! It seems that the problem is on Validate only.

Comment: Wish I was in your shoes! I'm still nowhere. Contacting Apple... Will let everyone know the solution once we hopefully get one.

Comment: I managed to submit it but then got an email from Apple saying "Invalid Provisioning Profile Location". Seems that's happening to a few people.

Comment: @JimBak Any luck with the DTS request yet?

Comment: @michaelwaterfall nothing yet. Been going back and forth.