# Issue at AppStore iOS app new version submission

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval, application-loader

Hello and thanks in advance.

While trying to submit new version of iOS App to AppStore using Application Loader, I received this message:

**ITC.apps.validation.prerelease_build_missing**

and submission is stopped. I didn't have any problems submitting new versions with prior versions of iTunesConnect, it seems that this bug is showing with latest version.

Have you any idea about what it means and how to solve the problem in order to proceed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to follow below steps to upload the application new version :

-- Give New Version details and Save the contents on itunes connect

-- Change the Bundle version in your application source code.

-- Upload the application with xCode 5.1.1 or later or Application    Loader 2.9.1 or later

-- After getting no issues found and application uploaded successfully, WAIT FOR TEN MINUTES.

-- After ten minutes, refresh the page of itunes connect.

-- Scroll down the screen, you will get a '+' icon in a blue circle in the BUILD section.

-- Click on the same and select the application version which you recently uploaded

-- Save all the changes and select "Submit for review"

Comment: Indeed, this appears to be the issue. It should be made a little more obvious methinks.

Answer (score 30):

All you have to do is scroll down on the main page of your version, spot the BUILD section and add there the build you have previousuly uploaded. Scroll up again and click "Submit for review".

That should do it.

Comment: You can't select a submitted build until you can actually upload a build. The question is about the inability to upload a build.

Comment: Brilliant! Love the new iTunes Connect UI, a bit slow tho.

Comment: Be patient. You may have to [wait a half hour or more](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25945496/642706) for your newly uploaded app to appear in the dialog box's list of builds from which you must choose when trying to add a "Build" record in the "Builds" area of the iTunesConnect "My Apps". Takes a while for Apple's backend servers to recognize the app you uploaded from Xcode.